# Get PostgreSQL replica list

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a Postgres database that uses physical replication. I want to get list of replicas.

Tried to `select * from pg_stat_replication`,I have two rows for replicas, but `client_hostname` field is empty. Documentation says that "it indicates that the client is connected via a Unix socket on the server machine". So how can I get replica connection strings/hostname/IP or any other way I can connect to replica to send query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it turned out to be the lack of permissions for user. I added him a corresponding role and everything fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get that by querying the primary server. All the primary server sees is the client IP address from which the standby server connects, and that could be on a different network or even (as in your case) using a different connection method from a client connection to the standby server.

Comment: So how can I get IP address? Actually, my goal is to send query to replica, so I can use IP address as host parameter

Comment: How can I configure replica connection so that I could get hostname from pg_stat_replication?

Comment: By by connecting to the primary on the same network as a client would use to connect to the standby.